# Can you please dump open id?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, openid

And use your own login system. Really. I don't visit very often, but each time I do I have to remember which provider I used for my open-id, which takes a couple tries, then click, fill out form, click, fill out another form. Other sites have a simple login and "Remember me" box. Why can't SO have it too?

#### Edit:

I have never cleared cookies.

Comment: shocked..!!! some one is against of it..

Answer (score 12):

Use cookies and never worry about logging in again (unless you are switching computers a lot).

I haven't had to relogin into this site from my home or work pc's in months.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I would reformulate your question with regard to *other* non-OpenID web sites out there:

> And use <strike>your own login system</strike> **OpenID**. Really. I don't visit very often, but each time I do I have to remember which <strike>provider</strike> **password** I used for my <strike>open-id</strike> **account on your web site**, which takes a couple tries, then click, fill out form, click, fill out another form. Other sites have a simple **OpenID** login and <strike>"Remember me" box</strike> **login is seamless**. Why can't <strike>SO</strike> **site XYZ** have it too?

Answer (score 7):

To me, OpenID seems one of the best features of the trilogy sites. Why bother remembering another username and another password when I already have enough of them? I can just click on the provider I have and be done with it.

Answer (score 4):

If you forget your OpenID provider URL, just use your own.
If you have your own domain, from a blog or website, you can use that as your Open ID login. All you have to do is to add two lines of html to your blog or website.

Here is an example for claimID (my open ID provider):

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://openid.claimid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.claimid.com/username" />
```

Here is some [more info from claimID](http://claimid.com/openid#delegate),
but this will work with other providers as well.

> Rather than logging in with
>   http://claimID.com/username, you'd log
>   in with http://myblog.com. Of course,
>   claimID will still be providing the
>   backend (no need for you to install
>   your own OpenID server!) so you'll be
>   asked for your password by claimID.
>   However, when you show up as a
>   commenter on a Livejournal thread, for
>   example, your blog or website will be
>   your OpenID url.

Answer (score 3):

First, why are you even logging out of the site?

**Part the second** - What makes you sure that you won't also forget your username and password combination on this site if it ever did use such a system?

**C** - OpenID is a simple log in. You sign in once at your provider, tell SO where it is and you're in like Flynn.

**IV** - You're doing something wrong if you're filling out all those extra forms.

Lastly, those other sites with "Remember me" are using cookies. Do you not like the Stack Overflow [cookies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25243/why-does-the-first-time-here-thing-have-to-flash-so-annoyingly/25247#25247)?

Comment: I haven't checked but if you don't log in for some period (1-2 weeks) you get logged out. I have this problem on my laptop (because I am using it infrequently, well at least until it died recently so now it's much less frequently). This is an understandable security precaution but considering the extra steps required for an OpenID logon, it's can be a bad user experience.

Comment: The natural fade away life span of a cookie is probably something like who knows when.  Been so long since logging out it's really all a blur.

Answer (score 1):

The coolest part of OpenID is using an existing account you already have and not creating a new one to remember.

You can have it remember yourself so you do not have to log in every time. Then when you click login on any of the sites, it will just log straight in.  No extra username/pw to remember.

Answer (score 1):

[myopenid.com](https://www.myopenid.com/) allows this. You are just using a bad OpenID provider or you don't understand what you are doing.

I can't even remember the last time I logged into OpenID.

Answer (score 1):

You could [**use your own URL**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/using-your-own-url-as-your-openid/) if you really can't remember which provider you registered with.

Answer (score -1):

The only site you actually have to login to post is this one.

You don't have to login at the trilogy sites if it's too difficult for you.